# determine whether we are in compose mode or edit mode

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins

Am working on an outlook add-in and using the OfficeJS API provided by Microsoft. I want to determine whether am in compose mode or edit mode.

I know I can use the displayForm API to check if am in compose or read mode.
But i want to know if there's a way to check if am editing an existing appointment.

```
    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm != undefined) {
        console.log("mode==========================================>read mode");
    } else {
        console.log("mode==========================================>compose mode");
    }
```

This piece of mode tells me am in compose mode , when editing an appoitment. Which is not what am searching for. Can I please get some help ?

Comment: Compose mode is the same as edit mode. Could you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks for replying. 
Its the same. But in edit mode, the fields contains pre-filled values such as title, location etc..
Whereas in 'compose mode', you open a blank appointment form with no pre-filled values.
So i want to know if its possible to know if its in 'edit mode' ?

Comment: To clarify you want to know if an appointment is new, or an appointment is an existing appointment. We currently don't have a way to tell that. You can tell if an item has ever been *saved* by doing a call to getItemIdAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#getitemidasyncoptions-callback) which will return an error if the item is not saved. I doubt this is what you want though, as anybody could save a new appointment, and then you couldn't tell the difference?

Comment: This is most likely a new feature request. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

if it's an existing appointment then it shouldn't have an "itemId"

You should be able to check this using the following code :

```
var itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
   // do something
}
```

more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentread?view=outlook-js-1.5#itemid)